# Setinterval run immediately in certain function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have code to get SQL data in Node.js JavaScript using mssql module and I managed to add in the set interval to get refreshed data every 10 minutes.

My code looks like this:

```
sql.connect(config, setInterval(
function () {   
var sqlcommit = fs.readFileSync('.//Commit.sql').toString();
var sqlcommit2 = fs.readFileSync('.//Commit_PG.sql').toString();

    var requestsql = new sql.Request();
    requestsql.query(sqlcommit, function(err, result) {     
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        //console.log(Date().toString() +'\n' + 'Refreshed Commit Query\n');
        D_commit = result.recordset;
        D_last_refresh = result.recordsets[1];  
    }   
    })
    
    var requestsql2 = new sql.Request();
    requestsql2.query(sqlcommit2, function(err, result) {       
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        //console.log(Date().toString() +'\n' + 'Refreshed Commit Query\n');
        D_commit2 = result.recordset;
        D_last_refresh2 = result.recordsets[1]; 
    }   
    })
}
,time)
)
```

However I when I run the Node.js, I need to wait for 10 minutes for the SQL function to start, is there a way to start the `setinterval` immediately when I started to run the Node.js in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can actually wrap the code in a function, run that once and tell your timer to keep that function on loop. :)

```
function loopedcode() {
    // your code here
    // executes right away
    setTimeOut(()=>{
        loopedcode();
    }, 10000);
}
loopedcode();
```

Comment: Hopefully this explains the process fairly well; I do try to avoid interval as its a rough version of Timeout. Heads up, more control this way; if need be we can define the timeout globally and run a catch to cancel its process, fast fast.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks
I manage to get it work by doing this though the code look abit long and messy.

```
sql.connect(config, setInterval(
function run () {   
//run query 
var sqlcommit = fs.readFileSync('.//Commit.sql').toString();
var sqlcommit2 = fs.readFileSync('.//Commit_PG.sql').toString();

    var requestsql = new sql.Request();
    requestsql.query(sqlcommit, function(err, result) {     
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        //console.log(Date().toString() +'\n' + 'Refreshed Commit Query\n');
        o.D_commit = result.recordset;
        D_last_refresh = result.recordsets[1];  
    }   
    })
    
    var requestsql2 = new sql.Request();
    requestsql2.query(sqlcommit2, function(err, result) {       
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        //console.log(Date().toString() +'\n' + 'Refreshed Commit Query\n');
        o.D_commit2 = result.recordset;
        D_last_refresh2 = result.recordsets[1]; 
    }})},time))

sql.connect(config, //setInterval(
function run () {   
//run query 
var sqlcommit = fs.readFileSync('.//Commit.sql').toString();
var sqlcommit2 = fs.readFileSync('.//Commit_PG.sql').toString();

    var requestsql = new sql.Request();
    requestsql.query(sqlcommit, function(err, result) {     
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        //console.log(Date().toString() +'\n' + 'Refreshed Commit Query\n');
        o.D_commit = result.recordset;
        D_last_refresh = result.recordsets[1];  
    }   
    })
    
    var requestsql2 = new sql.Request();
    requestsql2.query(sqlcommit2, function(err, result) {       
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        //console.log(Date().toString() +'\n' + 'Refreshed Commit Query\n');
        o.D_commit2 = result.recordset;
        D_last_refresh2 = result.recordsets[1]; 
    }   
    })
}
//,time)
)
```